# Laravel- PHP request not setting database values correctly

Tags: php, laravel, request, sql-update

I have a Laravel application, and on one of the pages, I want to allow the user to be able to update some values in the database, by entering/ changing data in a couple of textboxes.

The Angular function called by the `(change)` attribute of these HTML textboxes is:

```
updatePreferredAddresseeDetails($event, payer) {
    console.log("updatePreferredAddresseeDetails() called ");

    const contact = payer['contacts'][$event.currentTarget.selectedIndex]; 

    payer.loading = true;
    payer.originalAddresseeName = payer.addresseename;
    payer.originalAddresseeNamePdf = payer.addresseenamepdf;

    payer.ADDRESSEENAME = $event.contactPreferredName;
    payer.ADDRESSEENAMEPDF = $event.contactPreferredAddresseeName;

    this.provService.updatePreferredAddresseeDetails(payer).subscribe(
        (response:any) => {
            payer.addresseename = response.addresseename;
            payer.addresseenamepdf = response.addresseenamepdf;

            const message = new Message();
            message.type = MessageType.SUCCESS;
            message.message = 'Preferred Addressee details have been updated. ';
            this.messagingService.emitMessage(message);

            payer.loading = false;
        },
        (error:any) => {
            //reset the names back to what they were originally because saving failed
            payer.addresseename = payer.originalAddresseeName;
            const message = new Message();
            message.type = MessageType.ERROR;
            message.message = error.message || 'There was a problem updaing the preferred addressee details. If the problem persists, please contact us.';
            this.messagingService.emitMessage(message);

            payer.loading = false;
        }
    );
}
```

The PHP function called by the above Angular function, which should be setting the values in the database is:

```
public function updatePreferredAddresseeDetails(Request $request)
{
    try
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $transactionContactId = $request->input('transactionContactId');
        $transactionItemId = $request->input('transactionItemId');

        if ($transactionItem = transactionItem::find($transactionItemId))
        {
            $transaction = $transactionItem->transaction;

            if (User::canAccessTransaction( auth()->user()->user, $transaction))
            {
                $account = Account::find($transaction->accountId);
                $account->savePropertyValueByPropertyTag('ADDRESSEENAME', $request->input('contactPreferredName'));
                $account->savePropertyValueByPropertyTag('ADDRESSEENAMEPDF', $request->input('contactPreferredAddresseeName'));

                $account->save();

                DB::commit();

                return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'addresseeName' => $account->ADDRESSEENAME,
                    'addresseeNamePdf' => $account->ADDRESSEENAMEPDF,
                ]);
            }
            else
            {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                ]);
            }

            dd("transactionItem: ", $transactionItem);
        }
        else
        {
            dd("transactionItem could not be found ");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        if (empty($message))
        {
            $message = "Preferred addressee details could not be updated. ";
        }

        DB::rollback();

        return response()->json([
            'error' => true,
            'message' => $message
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

However, when I enter new values/ update an existing value in one of the textboxes, and then tab out of it, I can see in the browser console that the Angular function is called, and that it in turn calls the PHP function- but in the Network->Preview tab of the console, I see the output:

> {success: true, addresseeName: null, addresseeNamePdf: null}
>
> addresseeName: null
>
> addresseeNamePdf: null
>
> success: true

so for some reason, it seems that these values are not actually being updated in the database. Why is this? What am I doing wrong? How can I ensure that the database values are correctly updated from this function?

**Edit**

Looks like @Devon was possibly right with his comment about the function being used... I had a look the user.php file (which is where `canAccessTransaction()` is defined), and there was another function: `userCanEditAccount()`, which I think is probably the one I want. It's defined with:

```
private static function userCanEditAccount($userId, $accountId)
{
    return Account::canUserEditAccount( $userId, $accountId );
}
```

so I changed that part inside the `updatePreferredAddresseeDetails()` function to:

```
if(User::userCanEditAccount( $request->userId, $request->accountId)
{
    $account = Account::find($request->accountId);
    $account->savePropertyValueByPropertyTag('ADDRESSEENAME', $request->input('contactPreferredName'));
    $account->savePropertyValueByPropertyTag('ADDRESSEENAMEPDF', $request->input('contactPreferredAddresseeName'));

    $account->save();


    dd("request: ", $request->all());
    DB::commit();

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'addresseeName' => $account->ADDRESSEENAME,
        'addresseeNamePdf' => $account->ADDRESSEENAMEPDF,
    ]);
}
else
{
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
    ]);
}
```

But when the page loads now, before I actually interact with it at all, I get an error in the console that says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

on the line

```
$account = Account::find($request->accountId);
```

but I'm pretty sure that `;` should be there- what else could be causing this?

Comment: `Log::info($request->all());` Do the values you're trying to get exist there?

Comment: You're getting the right response, but `auth()->user()->user` looks wrong and I'm not sure what `savePropertyValueByPropertyTag` is supposed to do here.

Comment: If I add `dd("request: ", $request->all());` to the `updatePreferredAddresseeDetails()` PHP function, that shows the list of users available to select from the drop down for that field. However, it doesn't show the `addresseename` or `addresseenamepdf` fields that I'm trying to update in the database, or the value of the input fields from the form in the dialog (i.e. where the values should be coming from to update the database).

Comment: the `savePropertyValueByPropertyTag` is a function that should save the value of a field in a database table based on that field's name (i.e. in the account.property table, there are two rows whose 'propertyTag' values are `addresseename` & `addresseenamepdf`- it should be setting the values for these fields.

Comment: Does this method actually save the settings to the database or just sets them?  If you're not setting these values on the Account, then why are you calling `$account->save()` and trying to access `$account->ADDRESSEENAME`?

Comment: @Devon Thanks for your comments- it looks like you were possibly right about the function I was using... I've only recently joined the company, and had been told to look at another function as an example of what was going on/ what I need to do- which was using the `canAccessTransaction()` function. I had a look in the User.php file where that function is defined, and found one called `userCanEditAccount()`, which sounds like it is more likely to be what I need to use- I've given this a go, but am still having a few issues with it... I've updated my OP to reflect this.

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference, you were already hitting the success response..  Reread what I wrote about saving on the account..

Comment: As I understand, the line `$account->savePropertyValueByPropertyTag('ADDRESSEENAME', $request->input('contactPreferredName'));
     $account->savePropertyValueByPropertyTag('ADDRESSEENAMEPDF', $request->input('contactPreferredAddresseeName'));` should be saving the properties to the account...?